# too many thread count issue

Tags: multithreading, playframework, dispatcher

I have some questions about thread name in the PlayFramework.
I've developed Rest-API service on the Play for about 5 months.
The app simply accesses MySQL, and send back json formatted data to clients.
I've already understood the pit fall of the 'blocking io', so 
I create a thread pool for blocking io, and use it all the Future block that
 block thread execution.
The definition of the thread pool is as follows.

```
akka {
  actor-system = "myActorSystem"


  blocking-io-dispatcher {
    type = Dispatcher
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    thread-pool-executor {
      fixed-pool-size = 64
    }
    throughput = 10
  }
}
```

I checked the log file, and be sure that all non-blocking logics 
 run under thread named 'application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-#' where

## is integer value and that all blocking logics run under thread named

'application-blocking-io-dispatcher'.
Then I checked the all thread name and count using 'Jconsole'.
The number of thread named 'application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-#' is
 always under 13, and thread count of 'application-blocking-io-dispatcher-#'
 is always under 30. 
However, the total thread count of the JVM under which my app runs increases 
constantly. The total number of thread is more than 10,000.

There is so many threads whose name start with 'default-scheduler-' or 
'default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher'.

My questions are

a. What's the difference between 'application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher'
      and 'default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-' ?

b. Is there any reason thread count increases?

I want to solve this issue.
Here's my environment.

OS : Windows 10 Pro.  64bit

CPU : Intel(R) Core i7 @ 3.5GHz

RAM : 64GB

JVM : 1.8.0_162 64bit

PlayFramework : 2.6

RDBMS : MySQL 5.7.21

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem. There was a bug that would not shutdown the instance of 
akka's Materializor.  After modifying the code, thread count in the VM keeps stable value.
Thanks.